# Is there a way I can Pass xml ,start,limit in store.load?

Tags: extjs

I`m new to extjs,I need to pass a xml(xml data that`s loading grid),and start value,and limit.How can I do this in 'store.load'???

I actually need to display data in grid,with current pagenumber,and with limit.

Is there a way???plz help

Comment: 1. which version of extjs? 2. what are you actually trying to accomplish? 3. what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to setup a [page size](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-pageSize) and then use [store.loadPage()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadPage) method.

Bear in mind there is a nice [paging toolbar](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging) for data grid integrated in ExtJS